# What does the "service" time mean in Heroku logs?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

On Heroku Logs are outputted like this:

```
 25 Jul 2019 10:29:12.181323 <158>1 2019-07-25T08:29:11.494124+00:00 heroku router - - at=info method=POST path="/api/…” host=myhost request_id=b9cf8c3f-1e17-41ff-94bf-bb7edfcfaffb fwd=“123.123.123.123” dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=78477ms status=499 bytes= protocol=https
```

The service time in this example is 78 seconds (service=78477ms), which of course causes high response, and also takes up a lot of memory on the server, if we have more than one request hanging like that.

So to find the issue, I need to understand what the service time mean?

- Is it the time from connection start to connection end?
- or from the request have been received completely to connection end?
- or ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `service`: amount of time in milliseconds spent proxying data between the backend web process and the client

See in docs [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-router-log-format)

So in my understanding, this is full time from when the server starts receiving data from the client till the moment the response is fully sent from the server.